# i tried out binary search python problem bt the otp is not crt

Tags: python-3.x, binary-search

pos = -1

def search(list,n):

```
low=0
u = len(list)-1

while low <= u:
    mid = (low+u)//2

    if mid == n:
        globals()["pos"]=mid
        return True
    else:
        if list[mid] < n:
            low = mid+1
        else:
            u = mid-1
return False
```

list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,111,229,353,474,545,676,977,87778,999999]
n = 676

if search(list,n):
print('found at',pos+1)
else:
print("not found")

this is the code i written bt i cant find out the problem with this

Answer (score 0):

First `if` inside the `while` loop compares the position (mid) with the number itself (n):

```
if mid == n:
```

There you need to compare the number on that position (list[mid]) with n:

```
if list[mid] == n:
```

If you update this line it will work as expected.

Comment: If it helped, can you please set it as accepted answer? Thank you!